# Hugo: Escape special Characters in taxonomy (tag) paths

Tags: netlify, hugo

I have post tags like `C#` and `F#`. Similar cases also show up in titles.

The problem is that Hugo does not appear to support # in a url. Such pages 404 and fail my Netlify build.
With content pages, I can set an explicit url to get around the special character.

The same can't be done for the auto-generated taxonomy pages. How can I get hugo to escape or strip special characters (like #) from urls?

Note: [removePathAccents](https://gohugo.io/getting-started/configuration/#removepathaccents) doesn't apply for non-accent special chars like # or %

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set-up specific URL for almost anything in Hugo. To set-up a different URL for those tags:

1. Create a file: `./content/tags/C#/_index.md`
2. Set the following in it's frontmatter (YAML assumed):

```
url: "/tags/c-sharp"
```

Comment: Add-on: if you have a multi-language site the path is `./content/[lang]/tags/C#/_index.md`.